# Получение информации о вложенных окнах чужого приложения

Tags: python, windows, gui

UI Spy (Spy++ , SpyXX или аналоги) умеют "просматривать" все элементы приложения .Увидеть все древо с именами окон, хендлами и тд .
Вот пример :
[image: Spy UI]

Как пробраться внутрь , зная хендлы родителей  ? Как получить имена вложенных окон, кнопок и других сущностей. Хочу реализовать похожий функционал , как на скриншоте выше. Попробовал так добраться до имен вложенных окон :

```
import win32gui

parent_handle = 131588
child_handles = []
child_names = []

def all_ok(hwnd, param):
    child_handles.append(hwnd)
    child_names.append(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))

win32gui.EnumChildWindows(parent_handle, all_ok, None)

print(child_handles)
print(child_names)
```

Но получаю ошибку :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ПК/PycharmProjects/TESTING/2.py", line 12, in <module>
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(parent_handle, all_ok, None)
pywintypes.error: (126, 'EnumChildWindows', 'Не найден указанный модуль.')
```

Гугл не помог :(

Обновление.Как получить имя элемента , если он имеет хендл вида 42 197570 2 2 18 ( вложенный элемент, с пробелами) ?

Обновление 2. Что не так .Давайте разбираться . 
На картинке главное окно : 
[image: главное окно]

Действительно, хендл = 65922 .

```
import win32gui
hwnd = 65922
print(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
```

Output : 
PureVPN - Secure Virtual Private Network Connection (Administrator)

Но далее мы видим дочернее окно(кнопку без названия, но к ней мы тоже должны как-то обращаться, чтобы потом достать ее дочерние окна) :
[image: дочернее окно]

```
import win32gui

hwnd = 65922 # Parent window
nIDDlgItem = 27151449  # Что здесь должно быть  ?
h = win32gui.GetDlgItem(hwnd, nIDDlgItem)
print(h)
```

Завершается все это болью :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ПК/PycharmProjects/TESTING/3.py", line 5, in <module>
h = win32gui.GetDlgItem(hwnd, nIDDlgItem)
pywintypes.error: (1421, 'GetDlgItem', 'Не найден идентификатор элемента управления.')
```

Comment: а если переместить `2.py` например в `С:/`, и там выполнить?

Comment: Разобрался в чем проблема. Это не из-за русских символов в пути . Хотя, имя администратора поменяю, спасибо :)

Comment: Проблема в хендле детей . Если в родителя хендл 131588 , например , то у детишек 131588 2 , 131588  38 и тд. (с пробелом хендл) .  А приложения, которые сканируются данным кодом, имеют хендлы детей  нормальные , без пробелов.  Как можно решить  эту задачу ?

Comment: Скорее всего, это не хендл с пробелом, это `ID` дочернего окна указан через пробел. Дескриптор такого дочернего окна можно получить через вызов [GetDlgItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481(v=vs.85).aspx). Передавайте в `nIDDlgItem` значение после пробела, а в `hDlg` - значение перед пробелом

Comment: Ну вот `27151449` - вполне может быть дескриптором дочернего окна, а `2252` - у Вас выше указано, что это `PID`.

Comment: Пробовал и так : https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/8/31/ffad4eb3378d308d7578aeae3d3df368-full.png        .  Если бы это сработало, то потом две проблемы получалось бы : 1. Как получить эти дескрипторы ? Не руками же их вбивать. 2. Как быть с дескрипторами вида 42 197570 2 2 18 ?

Comment: `PID` - это идентификатор процесса, не окна. Его не надо передавать в `GetDlgItem`. Попробуйте просто разбить строку (split) по разделителю (пробел), и вызвать для каждой полученной подстроки [IsWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528(v=vs.85).aspx). Это даст гарантию, что подстрока - действительно дескриптор окна.  Возможно, вот эти одиночные числа - какие-то атрибуты, которые можно просто игнорировать в Вашем случае.